# Is there a way to show a google maps or open street map with image overlay on it on android NOT using webview?

Tags: java, android

Currently I have a `map` running on the `web` with Open **Street Map and Leaflet Library**. This `map` has an image overlay on it with `custom markers` (Image Example).[image] So, I am looking for a way to show the same map or another one on android but NOT using a **web view** (maybe using **Google Maps Api** or **OSM api**). It is possible. Is there any library that can achieve this ?
I really would appreciate your reply guys.
Thanks

Comment: You should explain what is this "image overlay" you are asking about.

Comment: As you can see on the image above the "image overlay" is and png image, I made this with L.ImageOverlay on Leaflet.

Comment: So it's a [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple) in terms of Google Map API.

Comment: And [here is image layer docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html) for OpenLayers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried osmdroid library? https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried with this library and save me a lot of time.